# Flutter Timer Duration

Tags: flutter

How do I watch the Timer Duration to do something  after a specific number of  minutes/seconds before it ends? 
var duration =  Duration(seconds:  time); Which will end in an hour. I want for example when time passed 30 minutes call a function OR anything else.

Comment: Unclear, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 12):

You can use `Future.delayed(...)`

```
new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: time), () {
  // deleayed code here 
  print('delayed execution');
});
```